# Spy a method that's returned by a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I want to spy on a method that's returned by a function.

I have this React component:

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import dashjs from 'dashjs';

// ... `Props` interface and PropTypes

export const Player: React.FC<Props> = ({ mpdUri }) => {
    const playerRef = useRef(dashjs.MediaPlayer().create());
    const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const video = videoRef.current;

        if (video) {
            playerRef.current.initialize(video, mpdUri, false);
        }
    }, [mpdUri]);

    return <video ref={videoRef} controls={false} />
};
```

Just remember that I'm creating a player with `dashjs.MediaPlayer().create()` and I'm trying to test if the player is initialized by `player.current.initialize(video, mpdUri, false)`.

Here's my current test:

```js
import dashjs from 'dashjs';
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { Player } from '.';

it('it initialize the player with the right data', () =>  { 
    const spy = jest.spyOn(dashjs.MediaPlayer().create(), 'initialize');

    mount(<Player mpdUri="fakeUri.mpd" />);

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    // ... expect arguments and maybe more
});
```

When I try to spy on `'initialize'`, Jest is telling me that it has never been called.

But if I spy on `'MediaPlayer'` with: `jest.spyOn(dashjs, 'MediaPlayer')` it does work (but that's not what I want).

NOTE: It also doesn't work if I spy on `'create'` with: `jest.spyOn(dashjs.MediaPlayer(), 'create')`. So this's probably not related to `useEffect`.

Comment: When you write player.current.initialize you mean playerRef.current.initialize ?

Comment: If I rename player to playerRef on your example it works!

Comment: @Max yes I meant `playerRef.current.initialize`. It works with `const spy = jest.spyOn(dashjs.MediaPlayer().create(), 'initialize');` in the test? I had to shorten the code so It can be understood, so this is why there's some little mistakes... But I've edited the question anyway!

Comment: Well I've just tested on a new CRA project but it doesn't work as I describe in the question.